# Why won't MySQL 8.0.28 install on macOS 12 Monterey?

Tags: mysql, installation, macos-monterey

I downloaded the community version of MySQL but it won't install on macOS. How come?

[image: MySQL 8.0.28-community can’t be installed on this computer.]

Comment: Are you downloading it the right architecture? The one you downloaded is for M1 CPU. If you are using Intel CPU, you should download the 2nd one, x86.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since the introduction of Apple M1 CPU, software like MySQL provided 2 versions for Apple M1 CPU (arm) and Intel CPU (x86).

Please make sure you downloaded the right version.

Comment: i tried the second one in the list and it works!

Answer (score 9):

I got the error below :

"mysql-8.0.31-macos12-x86_64.pkg” cannot be opened because it is from an unidentified developer."

Below steps resolved this issue on my mac m1.

1. Download the x86 version(DMG) for Mac M1.
2. Double click the DMG and it'll open the .pkg file.
3. Rather than double clicking on the .pkg file, right click and open the package.

Answer (score 7):

As an workaround you also could consider getting mysql from brew with `brew install mysql`.

Comment: Works like a charm without need to search ugly mysql website for proper installer or disabling ugly macos security to be able to install that. Also compared to installer does not force you to set complicated root password. Just install and run, perfect, thank you a lot.

Comment: this works for mac book m1 pro

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:
To download the MySQL Community Server, go to MySQL Community Downloads page and click Download button for macOS 11 (ARM, 64bit), DMG Archive. This will download the MySQL Community Server version 8.0. 27 file in your macOS' Download folde

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same issue. I was able to resolve it by downloading the x86 version on my Macbook

Comment: This seems to just restate the accepted answer with fewer details.